# Google App Script: How do I get only data range from named range?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

For example, I have data like this

[image]

And I named it

[image]

I used `Spreadsheet.getRangeByName` and got every cell in column A including blank rows

[image]

How do I get only range that has data (like in `Sheet.getDataRange`)

Output should be `[[data], [data], [data], [data]]`

Or `[[data,,,...and so on], [data,,,...], [data,,,...], [data,,,...]]` is acceptable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You have a named range of `test!A:A` as the name of `Data`.
- You want to retrieve the values from the named range and want to retrieve the data range from the named range.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const nameOfNamedRange = "Data"; // Please set the name of named range.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const values = ss.getRangeByName(nameOfNamedRange).getValues();
  const row = values.length - [...values].reverse().findIndex(r => r.findIndex(c => c.toString() != "") > -1);
  const colLen = values[0].length;
  const col = Math.min(...values.map(r => colLen - r.findIndex(c => [...c].reverse().toString() != "")));
  const res = values.splice(0, row).map(r => r.splice(0, col));

  console.log(res); // You can see the result values in the log.
}
```

- When this script is run, the values of the data range are retrieved from a named range.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: does get entire range like this cause performace issue?

Comment: @SoulCRYSIS Thank you for replying. About your additional question of `does get entire range like this cause performace issue?`, although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand `performace issue` you are thinking, for example, in my sample script, the last row and last column of the data range are retrieved from the named range. And, using these last row and column, the result values are retrieved. I think that in this flow, the process cost might be not large. If I misunderstood your additional question, I apoplogize.

Comment: Sorry for my bad endlish, I am not native. I heard that getting cell data from sheet is slow, so getting thousands of cell values should be very slow. Am I right?

Comment: @SoulCRYSIS Thank you for replying. About `Sorry for my bad endlish, I am not native. I heard that getting cell data from sheet is slow, so getting thousands of cell values should be very slow. Am I right?`, in my sample script, the values are retrieve by one request with `getValues()`. By this, the process cost is low. I think that in your reply, it might be the situation using `getValues()` and `getValue()` in a loop. In my sample script, please don't worry about it. And, when you tested my sample script, what result did you obtain?

Comment: your code output what I want and not slow at all. Thanks

Comment: @SoulCRYSIS Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

#### Get named ranges

```
function nr() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const nrs = ss.getNamedRanges();
  Logger.log(nrs.map(r => [r.getName(),r.getRange().getA1Notation()]))
}


Execution log
12:02:07 PM Notice  Execution started
12:02:06 PM Info    [[Sheet1, D4:G9], [one, C6:C8], [NamedRange1, C9:H11]]
12:02:08 PM Notice  Execution completed
```

[Spreadsheet.getNamedRanges](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getNamedRanges())